# What are some good commercially available services that can do forced alignment of a corrected transcript?

Tags: speech-recognition, transcription

I am looking for commercial solutions for automatically allocating time stamps for a the captions in a transcript. The service should take the transcript (sans the time stamps) and the corresponding audio file as an input and return the time stamps for the different captions in the transcript. 
Preferable if the service supports multiple language